# How to create a 100% screen width div inside a container in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say i have the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            ...
            <div class="full-width-div">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how to make `.full-width-div` stretch to the full width of the screen? Because currently it's limited inside the container.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**2019's answer as this is still actively seen today**

You should likely change the .container to .container-fluid, which will cause your container to stretch the entire screen. This will allow any div's inside of it to naturally stretch as wide as they need.

**original hack from 2015 that still works in some situations**

You should pull that div outside of the container. You're asking a div to stretch wider than its parent, which is generally not recommended practice.

If you cannot pull it out of the div for some reason, you should change the position style with this css:

```
.full-width-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Instead of absolute, you could also use fixed, but then it will not move as you scroll.

Comment: thanks, this worked. but i had to include left:0 as well.

Comment: Hi i try this code but this isn't work for me cause i'm using the col-sm-8 in the container can you please help me what i will do if I'm using a div in col-sm-8 and i want it on full screen width i mean 100% width.

Comment: How would you maintain the height of the div? It pulls everything below up..

Comment: this half works - because of absolute positioning it moves the element "away" from DOM (same applies to "fixed" except, it becomes relative to screen position). "relative" doesn't work also as it's relative to the parent (which is `.container` and if not will be child of .container) - not sure this is the ideal solution..

Comment: Position absolute will never work because it does not follow the flow of the content.

Answer (score 40):

You should use `container-fluid`, not `container`. See example: http://www.bootply.com/onAFpJcslS

Comment: not if you want to keep your page from strething and stuff like this

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your full-width-div doesn't stretch 100% to your screen it's because of its parent "container" which occupies only about 80% of the screen.

If you want to make it stretch 100% to the screen either you make the "full-width-div" position fixed or  use the "container-fluid" class instead of "container".

see Bootstrap 3 docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid