# How to make Bootstrap 3 full with for text on large screen without margin at the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make bootstrap full width for text on large screen but even though i have used `container-fluid` and [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049467/how-to-create-a-100-screen-width-div-inside-a-container-in-bootstrap) found on stackoverflow which should enables me to make a div full width, the text inside the div is still not full width. There is still a space at the right side of the screen on large screen as you can see in the demo

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="container-fluid ">

    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-12 ">

      <div class="full-width-div testons">
      dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd dfkjsdfjklsdf fsf asfsdfjdfasdf sdfsdfasd dfsdfas fasf sdfsdfas fasdfsd dfsdfas dfdsfa dfasfa faskdkfdk ajfdkjfjasd jafksdfjj afdfjksdf afdfsdf dfajkfjadkf afdfsf adfsdfs afdfdasf afsdf adfsfdf adfsdfsd afdsfsdf afdsfsd 
      </div>


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css aside of bootstrap**

```
html {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;

}


body {
  margin:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding:0; margin:0;

}

.testons {
    background:#14b5d1;
}

.full-width-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**How to make Bootstrap 3 full with for text on large screen without margin at the right ?**

Comment: Can you show what it looks like? I don't see the demo you're referencing

Comment: have you tried margin-right: 0?

Comment: Yes I just did yet nothing changed. I added it to `full-width-div `

Comment: `.row` or `.col-*-*` is the culprit; I forget which one, but by default, there is a 15px margin called a "gutter" on the left and right when using those elements.

Comment: Ok thanks but how to get rid of it. Apparently it is at the right. And even when I remove row and col I still have the same problem under container full

Answer (score 0):

`.row` and `.col-lg-12` - make no sense here. Just remove it

Comment: It still gives the same result even when i do unless you can please provide me with a working jsfiddle