# Possible to allow background overflow Bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The view is `good.Logo` is placed at the correct plave. But want the `background-color` too go wider than the `div`. (cover the hole widht of browser)

```
<div class="col-md-12 bannerwithlogo"></div>

.bannerwithlogo {
   height: 65px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   background:  url(//static.websitename.com/css/portals/websiteportal/gfx/logo.png) no-repeat top left;
   background-color: #c30c15;
}
```

Comment: Take a look here ---~ http://stackoverflow.com/a/24050049/5561605

Comment: I don't think you can make it bigger than the `div`, so you might need to wrap another `div` round the outside and set the `background-color` of that one.

Comment: please make a working example . put some effort into your question

Comment: Work with a relative `.bannerwithlogo` and `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: I think your parent div has "container" class. You need use "container-fluid" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 bannerwithlogo"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container-fluid{
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

.bannerwithlogo
{
  margin:10px 3px 0px 0px;
height: 65px;
background:  url(//static.websitename.com/css/portals/websiteportal/gfx/logo.png) no-repeat top left;
background-color: #c30c15;
}
```

CODE: http://www.bootply.com/Mn2erTu4HD