# Bootstrap: Div with 100% width inside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I want to create a div with full-width of the browser.
The div is inside a container and I couldn't change that structure.

Now the div inside the container has only the width of the container. Even if I set it to `position: absolute` like here: [How to create a 100% screen width div inside a container in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049467/how-to-create-a-100-screen-width-div-inside-a-container-in-bootstrap)

The div is a dropdown-menu inside the bootstrap navbar.
Is there any solution to get it to 100% of the screen size? Is there anything inside the navbar what changes the position/width?

This is my code:

```css
.dropdown-menu {min-width: 100%; position: absolute; display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the Basic bootstrap navbar with dropdown in it: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav

Comment: thanks, but now it stays on top even if i scroll down the page :(

Comment: Added another version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has a unit `vw`, which stands for viewport width. `1vw` represents 1% of the screen width.

Therefore, you can set `width: 100vw` to take up 100% of the screen width.

### Update

For current markup you can set `position: fixed`, but you'll have to set correct `top` value manually. Unfortunately **if your page is more than screen height** your menu will keep the same position. Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 56px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    top: 215px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

To achieve desired markup, you'll have to remove `position: relative` for all ancestors to apply absolute positioning relatively to window. So you'll have to fix all issues with this. Also you'll have to set `top` manually (because you are setting absolute positioning relatively to to window). Demo:

```css
/* delete relatively position */
.container,
.navbar,
.nav-item {
  position: static !important;
}

/* set absolute positioning */
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 55px !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  /* add centering for extra container */
  .flex-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  /* fix positioning for toggler */
  /* it will be broken to removed relative positioning for container */
  .navbar-toggler-right {
    position: static !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  
  .navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    top: 215px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="flex-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Also `position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0;` would allow you to specifiy the child’s dimensions independently from the parent.